# Could anyone provide an example which will generate ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException?

Tags: android

Android 12 adds restrictions on ForegroundService launched from some background tasks. I have an app which uses multiple ForegroundServices and some of them are not in the except cases. However, the build targeted to API 31 has not encountered any problem or ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException when the build runs on Android 12 Beta 4 devices.

Can anyone provide an example to have the problem after built target to API 31?

Answer (score 1):

in gradle:

```
compileSdkVersion 31
buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"
targetSdkVersion 31
```

in manifest:

```
 <service android:name=".MyForegroundService"
          android:exported="false"/>
       
<service android:name=".MyService"
         android:exported="false"/>

<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
          android:exported="true">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="com.sdk12.foreground.ACTION"/>
              </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Receiver:

```
class MyBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Log.d("tag", "onReceive()");
        val myServiceIntent = Intent(context, MyForegroundService::class.java)
            Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({ 
                try {
                    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context,myServiceIntent)
                } catch (ex : ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException){
                    Log.d("tag","ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException")
                }
            }, 5000)
        }
}
```

foreground service:

```
class MyForegroundService : Service() {
    private lateinit var br: BroadcastReceiver

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        br = MyBroadcastReceiver()
        val filter = IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION).apply {
            addAction(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED)
        }
        registerReceiver(br, filter)

    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        val channelId = createNotificationChannel("channel1","My Background Service")

        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent =
            Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).let { notificationIntent ->
                PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
            }

        val notificationBuilder = Notification.Builder(this, channelId )
        val notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("contentText")
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_SERVICE)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setForegroundServiceBehavior(Notification.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE)
            .build()

        startForeground(1, notification)

        return START_STICKY

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(br)
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel(channelId: String, channelName: String): String {
        val chan = NotificationChannel(
            "channel1",
            channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE
        )
        chan.lightColor = Color.BLUE
        chan.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
        chan.importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(chan)
        return channelId
    }
}
```

My Service:

```
class MyService : Service() {
    private lateinit var br: BroadcastReceiver

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        br = MyBroadcastReceiver()
        val filter = IntentFilter("com.sdk12.foreground.ACTION")
        registerReceiver(br, filter)

    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
        return START_STICKY
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(br)
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

trigger service:

```
startService(Intent(this, MyService::class.java))
```

send your app to background and call from adb:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.sdk12.foreground.ACTION -f 0x01000000
```

this will make sure you are in background
probably there are easier ways, but I find this most understandable

Comment: Wait, this is to reproduce this issue?

Comment: yes, it was reproduced for me from receiver and not from a service

Comment: For some reason, even though I use try-catch, there are times it doesn't catch it. I have no idea why. Really annoying all those restrictions...

Comment: 1. is the exception thrown?
2. does it happen on their latest release?

Comment: 1. Yes, it's thrown. That's why it crashes. Thing is, in the stack-trace (via Crashlytics), I don't see any call of my app's classes. It's like the service was started out of nowhere. 2. Yes. Also reported this here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203557331